# How to add more tables to Magento database Schema?

Tags: database, magento

We have an issue with respect to adding tables to Magento Schema.
Problem: we have a 3rd party custom built ERP  system, which we need to integrate with up coming Ecommerce soltuion.
 We want to create few tabels, whose table structure is exactly the same as the ERP one. This is planned for our future sync process with the ERP related to the products, inventory ..etc
 But we don't know 
     how to create these tables in Magento...? Or
     whether Magento allows to create additional tables ?
     If we can create, what changes does it causes that we need to be sure ?

Please if anyone in the community has answers to any of the questions that we have, please let us know.

Thanks in advance

Kiran

Answer (score 1):

Too broad There is no such thing to create tables in Magento unless you mean creating them directly in the DB.
Maybe you should take a look to the import/export functions in magento to integrate to your ERP or even better the web services (SOAP, XML-RPC) api.